# Zero free region of Riemann zeta function

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta

For the zeros of the Riemann zeta function, $\rho=\beta+i \gamma$, is there a zero free region near $\beta=0$? I am familiar with the zero free regions near $\beta=1$, such as $\beta<1-1/\log(T)$ for $T>|\gamma|$, but I am mostly curious about the other end of the critical strip.

Comment: Consider the functional equation which relates the values of $\zeta$ near $\beta=1$ to the values where $\beta=0$. This should help answer your question

Comment: Thank you. Any hints on what that equation may be? @DavidSheard

Comment: Yes, check out the section on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#Riemann's_functional_equation) page for the $\zeta$ function